# Website loads a lot of data on iOS safari for an angular web application

Tags: ios, angular, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm working on an Angular web application that has a feature voice recording for 10 seconds and sends it as a blob to the server.

This feature can be used by the user multiple times, after using this for a day on iOS safari, I went on to my device settings > Safari > Advance > website data I noticed my website data is 100+ MB. But the actual bundle size of my angular application is about 7MB.

Why is the data is increasing drastically?

Searched in various ways to find a solution but no luck.

[image]

Comment: `after using this for a day`... well 7 * 15 = 105. So, how much is actually "a day"? Also, how large are the blobs you're sending?

Comment: @JamesZ well, I mean after using it for about 10-12 hours. And my blob size is around 1.05MB approximately.